# Vim substitutes only first occurence in line (global tag not working)

Tags: vim

Let's say I want to change All occurrences of 'foo' to 'bar' on a line.
I'd do this with

```
:s/foo/bar/g
```

For some reason it only substitutes the first occurrence of 'foo'.
Why could be causing this?

Comment: `g` means global. So, it should substitute all occurrences in the line. Start vim like `vim -u None filename` and then substitute, it will work. In that case, you have some issue or setting set off.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11812615/what-causes-substitution-in-vim-to-only-match-one-element-per-line/11812628#11812628

Comment: Beautiful! Thanks @FDinoff, I somehow missed that topic.